# Convergence test of $\int _0^{\infty } \frac{x^3+x^2}{x^6+1}\sin\left(2x\right)dx$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, solution-verification

Hello I'm trying to test the convergence of a certain integral here but I'm not sure if my solution is right? Can someone confirm?

$$\int _0^{\infty } \frac{x^3+x^2}{x^6+1}\sin\left(2x\right)dx=\int _0^2\frac{x^3+x^2}{x^6+1}\sin\left(2x\right)dx+\int _2^{\infty } \frac{x^3+x^2}{x^6+1}\sin\left(2x\right)dx.$$

We can say that $\int _0^2\frac{x^3+x^2}{x^6+1}\sin\left(2x\right)dx$ converges.

For the next integral we can compare with $\int _2^{\infty } \frac{dx}{1+x^2}$.

$$\int _2^{\infty } \frac{x^3+x^2}{x^6+1}\sin\left(2x\right)dx\le \int _2^{\infty } \frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\frac{\pi }{4}-\arctan\left(2\right).$$

From the comparison test we can say that $\int _0^{\infty } \frac{x^3+x^2}{x^6+1}\sin\left(2x\right)dx$ converges.

Comment: How can it be compared with $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$? I don't see why.

Comment: Comparison test works only for nonnegative integrands. So basically you have to find a majoration of $\left|\dfrac{x^3+x^2}{x^6+1}\sin\left(2x\right)\right|$ by something integrable to conclude.

Comment: @Riemann Because $\frac{1}{1+x²}$ is a function that's greater over 0 to infinity.. so if that converges the initial integral converges

Comment: @TheSilverDoe So with absolute values it would've been correct?

Comment: I think simply we can compare with $\frac{x^3+x^2}{x^6} = \frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x^4}$ since the denominator does not vanish if $x\ge 2$.

Comment: @Savantik You need to estimate the absolute value. $\sin$ can take negative values, having an upper bound does not mean your integral cannot diverge to $-\infty$.

Comment: @Riemann I could try that as well!

Comment: @Gary Would it had worked if I'd used absolute values?

Comment: @Savantik Yes, if you get the inequality $$\left|\dfrac{x^3+x^2}{x^6+1}\sin\left(2x\right)\right|\leq \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$$ on $[2, +\infty)$, it would work. (But IMO, this inequality needs an explanation).

Comment: @Savantik Yes, note that $$
\left| {\int_2^\infty  {\frac{{x^3  + x^2 }}{{x^6  + 1}}\sin (2x)dx} } \right| \le \int_2^\infty  {\frac{{x^3  + x^2 }}{{x^6  + 1}}\left| {\sin (2x)} \right|dx}  \le \int_2^\infty  {\frac{{x^3  + x^2 }}{{x^6  + 1}}dx} .
$$

Comment: Okay, thanks for helping!

Comment: I have one more thing to add maybe, can we compare the integral with a series $\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }\:\frac{n^3+n^2}{n^6+1}sin\left(2n\right)$, or is the integraltest for series not both ways?

Comment: @Savantik The integral test is for monotonic functions. Since you have a sine function, yours is not monotonic. You may use Dirichlet's test instead.